# define other url in config codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I want to define another url in the config file

codeigniter default base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.domain.com/backend';
```

I defined another url

```
$config['front_url'] = 'www.domain.com/frontend';
```

when I call front_url(); 
it gives error 
Call to undefined function front_url()

Comment: And what is front_url basiclly?

Comment: because i want to show some backend data on front end and used in permalink like <?php echo anchor('pages/template?id='$id, ''.front_url().'/index.php/template/'); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base_url() is a function, you can find this function in url_helper.php file (you must load the helper to use it).

If you want to use front_url() as a function, you must create your own function, like base_url(), in your own helper :

```
public function front_url($uri = '')
{ 
    // If used in helper, you must get instance
    $ci &= get_instance();
    $front_url = $ci->config->item('front_url');

    return $front_url . ltrim($uri, '/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use style . I hope it will use full for you

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
      {
        $site_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
        $site_url .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $site_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

```
    // Base URI (It's different to base URL!)
    $site_uri = parse_url($base_url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    if(substr($site_uri, 0, 1) != '/') $site_uri = '/'.$site_uri;
    if(substr($site_uri, -1, 1) != '/') $site_uri .= '/';
  }

else
  {
    $site_url = 'http://static_location/';
    $site_uri = '/';
  }
// Define these values to be used later on
define('BASE_URL', $site_url);
define('BASE_URI', $site_uri);
define('APPPATH_URI', BASE_URI.APPPATH);

// We dont need these variables any more
unset($site_uri, $site_url);

$config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
base_url() in CI function which returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file.

First you define a base_url() in config.php
  $config['base_url']   = 'www.domain.com/backend';

then define your custome url path
  define('front_url',$base_url.'front_url');

Now you can access this in controller or view or helper like this 
    $image_path  = $front_url.'/image';
```